# Sub Menus items are not showing in mobile in Joomla site

Tags: joomla

I have developed a website in Joomla. Used "**Megamenu**" for menu.

The menu having some sub menu items. Sub menu items are displaying in Desktop, but not in mobile devices.

This is my website url...

http://dlawgroup.com/site/

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me link for demo version of your MegaMenu? Try to go on Templates/Style/your_template and find MegaMenu option and check there, maybe you disable dropdown for mobile.